# How to animate component repositioning on recomposition in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: animation, android-jetpack-compose

I have two squares. The green one is constrained to the top, and the blue one is constrained between the green one and the bottom of the screen. When clicking on the blue square, the green square doubles in size. Since the size of the green square increases, the blue square moves downwards because of its constraints.

How do I animate the position change of the blue square? Do I have to manually calculate and animate the offset? This feels very hacky. I feel like this should be doable declaratively, since the new position is automatically calculated by the updated constraints.

Edit: Basically, I'm looking for `android:animateLayoutChanges`, but for Compose.

Here is my code:

```
@Composable
fun AnimationTest() {
    ConstraintLayout(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        val (block1, block2) = createRefs()
        var blockSize by remember { mutableStateOf(20.dp) }

        Surface(
            color = Color.Green,
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(blockSize)
                .constrainAs(block1) {
                    top.linkTo(parent.top)
                    start.linkTo(parent.start)
                    end.linkTo(parent.end)
                }
        ) {}

        Surface(
            color = Color.Blue,
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(50.dp)
                .constrainAs(block2) {
                    top.linkTo(block1.bottom)
                    start.linkTo(parent.start)
                    end.linkTo(parent.end)
                    bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
                }
                .clickable {
                    blockSize *= 2
                }
        ) {}
    }
}
```

[image: Animation]

Comment: @jayeffkay Unfortunately not. I don't think there is an explicit way for managing this. I did find out however that `AnimatedVisibility` has this logic embedded in it. So in the example of this post, the blue square position will be animated if the green square is shown by using `AnimatedVisibility`. But if you don't want to use that API, there is no easy solution I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping it inside the `AnimatedContent` composable. Though it is `ConstraintLayout` so I don't think it would work, but it just might. Give it a try and let me know. Otherwise, it is a very simple scenario, and can be easily achieved with the `Layout` composable, inside which you can use `lerp()` to achieve the animation

Comment: I tried it, but I don't think `AnimatedContent` is supposed to be used for this. It will just crossfade the entire layout. I want it to have an internal reference to its previous instance and see that only the yPosition needs to be changed (and animated). I also don't see how that's possible with a custom Layout. Can you provide an example of this?